# Visual Studio 2008 script documents full of "eval code"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, model-view-controller, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2, web-applications

Running Visual Studio 2008 MVC 2 (bug fixes on older web application). In between each page this list of files named "eval code" shrinks and then expands again. I have not figured out a way to get it to stop or a reason that it's occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how the client part of your application 'breathes'. Each dynamically generate portion of JS is being delegated to eval statement and then executed by browser's JS engine. If you double click any, you will see what exactly is being executed. It is usually hand-written JS statements to be injected on-the-fly, or ASP.NET web resources (AXD) files.
You can disable this by IE options -> Advanced -> Disable Script Debugging (Other) yet this will not allow you to attach to a process and debug client side code from Visual Studio (you'll have to use IE development tools [F12])

Comment: I write code for a bank that uses ie exclusively. But I might consider using something else when I am debugging script and disabling it in ie for everything else. Breaths huh... I would like to choke it. :0)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does some fancy work to integrate itself with Internet Explorer, making it possible to set breakpoints and debug bits of javascript within the Visual Studio IDE.

I personally prefer using Firebug for my javascript debugging, so this isn't much of an issue for me. :-P

One thing to be aware of, however, is that if this list is very large, there's a good possibility you're generating way more script blocks than you need to. You may want to consider offloading your javascript into static *.js files, which can be effectively cached, and then using "unobtrusive javascript" techniques to avoid the need for inline snippets of javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

eval code is generated  by the visual studio when ever you run the asp.net application. since in-order to load the dlls which are needed. This is must.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps for visual studio 2008

1)

```
32Bit: start->run, cmd.exe
64Bit: start->run, c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe
```

2)      Run this commands:

a.       to close:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f
```

b.      to open:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {170EC3FC-4E80-40AB-A85A-55900C7C70DE} /f
```